# Minecraft ArmorStand Teleportation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm using SethBling's armorstand posing help and I'm trying to teleport an invisible stand to an already set stand but I'm having troubles understanding how the teleports work. I know the commands but I don't know how to control which way the stand will move, can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Maddie, _not_ Seth Bling here, can you link to the video and show us your command that's moving the stands right now?

Comment: This is the video I used [ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoLRLKyswTI ] and the command I'm using is /tp @e[type=ArmorStand,r=5] ~ ~ ~                          but even after I rotate the armor stands they still only move one direction. I don't know if there is a way to make them move another way or a way to move to them to spiefic location.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to move one entity to another is this syntax of `/tp`:

```
/tp <Target Selector> <Destination Selector>
```

This teleports the target entity/entities to the destination entity/entities.

For example, for your situation, to teleport the ArmorStand within 1 block of you to an ArmorStand at least 1 block away from you:

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,r=1] @e[type=ArmorStand,rm=1]
```

---

You can also use `/tp` with either absolute or relative coordinates, like this:

```
/tp <Target Selector> <x> <y> <z>
```

For example, to teleport the nearest ArmorStand to x=0, y=64, z=10 you could do:

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,c=1] 0 64 10
```

Or to teleport an ArmorStand called "Decoration" up 2 blocks and to the north one block, you could do:

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Decoration] ~ ~2 ~-1
```

Note that a <kbd>~</kbd> before a number means the coordinate is relative to the entity's current position. e.i. moving 2 blocks upwards rather than to the absolute value of y=2.

---

Selecting and moving entities around is fairly easy, but requires some basic knowledge of different command parts. You could use these wiki links to learn more about:

- [Commands in general](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands)
- [The TP command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#tp)
- [Selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors)
- [Coordinates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Coordinates)