# Weird Error Message to /tp

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building a map and I'm trying to teleport a Armor Stand named Jacob, but it tells me:

> '888ba526-c645-4271-8ca7-5bf8cca13344' is not a valid number

Here is the command:

```
/tp @e[name=Jacob] -459.1 202.0 -840.4
```

I'm using minecraft 1.10.2. I have no mods installed.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you need to make it target an armor stand in []? Also, please include a screenshot and the version you're using, and if your using mods

Comment: Alright Alex, i added in more info

Comment: hmm... that's strange, I've never seen that before

Comment: I don't know if i did something wrong with the command or anything, because the command always worked... Is there a new way to /tp ArmorStands in 1.10.2?

Comment: I think you'll have to wait for someone who knows how to do commands better than me to answer

Comment: yeah, I'm waiting for colorfusion to find this

Comment: If I had to guess, the armor stand inherited or already had that GUID (global unique identifier AKA that long string of numbers and letters) and now something is wrong with it. Have you tried making a new armor stand an teleporting it? What happens then?

Comment: it says the same thing with different number & letters

Comment: Does ANYONE have an awnser

Comment: Maybe try the answer in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/215458/163757).  It's not a direct answer but maybe you have the syntax wrong for your command.

Comment: Nope, didn't help me.

Comment: ... this happened to me yesterday and today i try it and it works...

Comment: I recognize the format of that string... the skull is causing the problem. I'm not sure how to fix it, but the custom player skull is the issue. They did some weird thing in 1.8 and made it where you have to use that for certain things, not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know how to fix the problem! When you teleport an entity, you have to specify which type of entity you want the teleport and not just the name of it. So, to teleport your armor stand you would do `/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Jacob]  -459.1 202.0 -840` to teleport it to that location! I hope my command and answer worked for you and if it didn't work please tell me what the result was, Thank You!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. Soz