# Teleporting behind player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How is it possible to teleport an armour stand behind a player (with its position updating as the player moves) in 1.15+?

Comment: Hi NotSaz, a few questions: resemble what stands? What's a "jojo stand thing"? What exactly do you want and what have you actually done?

Comment: I'm talking about Jojo's bizzare adventure,stand is like a visual manifestation of life energy that has abilities beyond that of a human and they stand like flying near the user,so i made all abilities and my friends made the design but we don't know how to do it stand in the air near a player

Comment: The information is mostly irrelevant to the core of the question, @Joachim - he just wants to be able to teleport behind a player.

Comment: teleport an armor stand behind a player*

Comment: [This related question and answer from 5 years ago](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/215458/minecraft-armorstand-teleportation) look very similar to yours (and were automatically suggested as potentially related by SE). Do they answer your question? (If not, you might want to edit your question and clarify how it's different from the earlier one.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sorry but my question is about teleporting armor stands in a specific position near the player

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a [scoreboard tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags_commands) for each player and armor stand pair to use this command.

```
/execute as @e[tag=stand1,type=minecraft:armor_stand] positioned as @a[tag=stand1] run teleport @s ~ ~1 ^-1 facing ^ ^ ^
```

This command should teleport an armor stand to the nearest player, one block above and one behind them.

Breakdown of command:
`/execute as @e[tag=stand1,type=minecraft:armor_stand]` - This will pick an armor stand with the scoreboard tag "stand1" and execute the command from it.
`positioned as @p[tag=stand1]` - Sets all the relative positions used with `~` and `^` to be relative to the player with the scoreboard tag "stand1".
`run teleport @s ~ ~1 ^-1` - Teleports the armor stand to the player, up one block, and one block behind the direction the player is facing.
`facing ^ ^ ^` - Causes the armor stand to face the same direction the player's head is.

Comment: This answer probably isn't in its most efficient state - I have asked more experienced players for help, so they may update the answer soon.